# when i enter only min value then it consider max as zero and return me null data

Tags: php, sql

When I enter only min value then it consider max as zero and return me null data

```
$min=$_REQUEST['min'];     
$max=$_REQUEST['max'];     
$q3="select * from product where '$min' < `price` < '$max'";    
$q=mysql_query($q3);
```

Comment: what do you mean null data? you haven't even fetched the rows yet. and please stop using `mysql_` functions. use mysqli or PDO instead with prepared statements

Comment: `when i enter only min value then it consider max as zero `: So when you dont provide max what should max be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the query by max value:

```
$min=$_REQUEST['min'];

$max=$_REQUEST['max'];

if( empty($max) )
   $q3="select * from product where price > '$min'";
else
   $q3="select * from product where price > '$min' and price < '$max' ";


$q=mysql_query($q3);
```

One more correction you should start using PDO . method your are using is depreciated.

[Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not provide value in your request, php will consider it as NULL. You should have to provide value every time or you can do this .

```
$min=$_REQUEST['min'];

$max=$_REQUEST['max'];

if(!$max){
   $max = 45; // or what ever value you like
}

$q3="select * from product where price > '$min' and price < '$max' ";

$q=mysql_query($q3);
```

Comment: `$max you have backtick here, change it to single quete

Comment: i was talking about your query first you got backtiks in `$max`